# Best practice to generate cached request results

Tags: mysql

I'm building a custom backoffice dataviz tool for a client. This tool generates a lot of graphs, maps and tables to help the marketing team analyze the client needs.
The tool uses filters that the client will use to navigate the data. Each time the filter is set, the tool generates the filtered base tables on which the rest of the requests are based : extract position for a map, extract time for a time series...

This is not working, the request are awfully long. The client is OK to sacrifice the freshness of the data for the usability of the tool, and I'm buiding a script that prepares prefiltered tables during the night.
This works fine, but I have a feeling I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here.

I'm wondering what are the best practices for that :

- I have choosen to run an external script instead of triggers, because I've been told it's easyer to debug.
- I am creating a ton of tables, I didn't want to use views because they are virtual table and as such are not fit for my purpose of pre-processing as much as possible in advance.
- I am overwriting the tables, but maybe it would be better to update them ?

Do you have any comment or suggestions ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Presumably we're talking about vast data sets here.

Comment: the 4 main tables have around 90k rows